# MongoDB : request to get the first record for each hour

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

In a MongoDB, I want to make an hourly stat.
For that, I will search for all documents with a timestamp between 00:00 and 00:05, 01:00 and 01:05, etc..
(data are imported once every 5 minutes)

Here is an example of stored documents. the timestamp is an UNIX timestamp (without milliseconds)

```
  {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6606355bfe62086d368df1"),
        "timestamp" : 1511492352,
        "value" : 2.0
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6606355bfe62086d368e20"),
        "timestamp" : 1515556761,
        "value" : 3.0
    },
```

my current query looks like this, but it doesn't work

```
.find({new Date(timestamp*1000).getMinutes():{ $lt: 5 }} )
```

please help me to find the correct query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the syntax :

```
.find("new Date(this.timestamp*1000).getMinutes() < 5")
```

Comment: btw, doing that way makes the query very slow.

the solution is to create a specific collection and populate exactly the data you want inside it, It will speed up the collection reading because there's no exotic "find" close to evaluate on each document.